# How to make both values change?

Tags: python

I want to make a blackjack game on repl.it, and so far I have the basics down. However, when I try to change the Ace into a 1, only one value changes. I've tried changing the positions of the append and remove, switching them. When I enter cardListTotal into the console, the output is ''A', 1', and I want to get both values to be '1, 1' Here is the code:

```
cardList = ['A', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K']

cardListSpecial = ['A', 'J','Q','K']

playerCard1Drawn = cardList[random.randint(0,0)]
playerCard2Drawn = cardList[random.randint(0,0)]
playerCard3Drawn = cardList[random.randint(0,12)]

playerDeck = [playerCard1Drawn, playerCard2Drawn]
cardListTotal = [playerCard1Drawn, playerCard2Drawn]

print("You drew " + str(playerCard1Drawn) + " and " + str(playerCard2Drawn))

while 'A' in cardListTotal or 'J' in cardListTotal  or 'Q' in cardListTotal or 'K' in cardListTotal:
  if 'A' in cardListTotal:
    cardListTotal.append(1)
    cardListTotal.remove('A')
  if 'J' in cardListTotal:
    cardListTotal.remove('J')
    cardListTotal.append(10)
  if 'Q' in cardListTotal:
    cardListTotal.remove('Q')
    cardListTotal.append(10)
  if 'K' in cardListTotal:
    cardListTotal.remove('K')
    cardListTotal.append(10)
```

Comment: The loop condition must look like "while 'A' in cardListTotal or 'J' in cardListTotal or..."

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank you for helping, but it still gives the same result. I edited the code to what you said and nothing changed.

Comment: I oversaw the "break" in the last line, remove it.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Break removed, error persisted.

Comment: Never mind, I'm dumb and didn't change everything on my side. Thanks for your help!